# system call or dlsym? Which way is faster?

Tags: c

I call a system call like `write()` in C, on the other hand I invoke `write()` using `dlsym()` in this way:

```
ssize_t original_write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count)
{
    typedef ssize_t (*orig_write_type)(int, const void *, size_t);
    static orig_write_type orig_write;
    if (!orig_write)
        orig_write = (orig_write_type) dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "write");
    ssize_t ret = orig_write(fd, buf, count);
    return ret;
}
```

I am curious which way is faster? When I call `write()`, it will also implicitly call `dlsym()` to get its address? Please correct me. Many thanks for your time.

Comment: The compiler will probably turn both into the very same code.

Comment: What's faster? You can measure that yourself...

Comment: C says nothing about `dlsym()` -- it is not among the standard library functions defined by C.  Moreover, I would be very surprised to find any implementation using `dlsym()` to implement function calls into dynamic libraries.  Systems featuring dynamic libraries ordinarily have some form of dynamic linker that makes it unnecessary.  But overall, *why in the world would you want to add such an ugly mess to your program*?

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to "which is faster" questions, use a profiler and time the code yourself.

That being said, a static call will always be faster then a dynamic call for the first call.  Once the function has been loaded dynamically, the two should run at *nearly* the same speed. The dynamic approach shown uses a couple of extra instructions to check the `static` variable, so the dynamic call won't be *exactly* as fast as the static call.

You can avoid that by getting rid of the `static` variable altogether. Write a stub function and declare a function pointer variable that points at that stub. Have the stub load the real function, update the variable to point at it, and then call it. Then you can use the function pointer for all of your calls. The first time will call the stub, every subsequent time will call the real function directly.